# How to compare the same columns in different rows?

Tags: oracle, pivot-table

I have extracted data like below

```
Name   Session     CATEGORY   HT     WT     BMI
John   SESSION 1   OW         1.5    64.6   28.71
John   SESSION 3   OW         1.52   63.2   27.35
Eric   SESSION 1   OW         1.48   55.7   25.43
Eric   SESSION 3   OW         1.52   55.4   23.98
```

I would want it in the below format

```
Name  session_1_Category  Session_1_height  session_1_weight  session_1_BMI  session_3_Category  Session_3_height  session_3_weight  session_3_BMI
John  OW                  1.5               64.6              28.71          OW                  1.52              63.2              27.35
Eric  OW                  1.48              55.7              25.43          OW                  1.52              55.4              23.98
```

I'm using oracle database. Please help me with a SQL query to extract data in the above format.

Comment: Look for Pivot in Oracle

Comment: Are there only ever 2 sessions per name in the data?

Comment: So John's 'SESSION 3' becomes "Session 2" in your results, because it's his second session ordered by alfabet?

Comment: Yes there are at most 2 sessions per name, but for some names there will be only session 1, in those cases session 2 data should be null.

Comment: Have you considered `select * from mytable order by name, session` and making the layout (in a grid or table) in your app or website? Seems the straight-forward way to me and very flexible at that (e.g. dynamically detect more than two sessions in the future).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `PIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f7fc9/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( Name, "Session", CATEGORY, HT, WT, BMI ) AS
SELECT 'John', 'SESSION 1', 'OW', 1.5,  64.6, 28.71 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'John', 'SESSION 3', 'OW', 1.52, 63.2, 27.35 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Eric', 'SESSION 1', 'OW', 1.48, 55.7, 25.43 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Eric', 'SESSION 3', 'OW', 1.52, 55.4, 23.98 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT(
  MAX( HT ) AS height,
  MAX( WT ) AS weight,
  MAX( BMI ) AS BMI
  FOR "Session" IN (
    'SESSION 1' AS Session_1,
    'SESSION 3' AS Session_3
  )
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f7fc9/3/0)**:

```
| NAME | CATEGORY | SESSION_1_HEIGHT | SESSION_1_WEIGHT | SESSION_1_BMI | SESSION_3_HEIGHT | SESSION_3_WEIGHT | SESSION_3_BMI |
|------|----------|------------------|------------------|---------------|------------------|------------------|---------------|
| John |       OW |              1.5 |             64.6 |         28.71 |             1.52 |             63.2 |         27.35 |
| Eric |       OW |             1.48 |             55.7 |         25.43 |             1.52 |             55.4 |         23.98 |
```

Comment: Thank you. I used pivot like select * from (select * from some_table where some_condition='some_value') pivot (pivot_conditions);

Comment: If I want to compare session 1 height with session 3 height, and session 1 weight with session 3 weight, how can I do it?

e.g. if SESSION_1_HEIGHT =SESSION_3_HEIGHT then height_status=true else height_status=false

 if SESSION_1_WEIGHT =SESSION_3_WEIGHT then weight_status=true else weight_status=false

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution without using PIVOT tables and will work across platforms-

```
SELECT NAME
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 1' THEN CATEGORY END) AS session_1_Category
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 1' THEN HT END) AS Session_1_height
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 1' THEN HT END) AS session_1_weight
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 1' THEN HT END) AS session_1_BMI
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 3' THEN HT END) AS session_3_Category
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 3' THEN HT END) AS Session_3_height
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 3' THEN HT END) AS session_3_weight
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Session = 'SESSION 3' THEN HT END) AS session_3_BMI
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY NAME
```